# Can the Sprint RESTful server support Accept=application/xml

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Everything I've read says the Sprint RESTful server talks with the client passing JSON. What if the client passes up XML and has Accept=xml for the response. Will it then communicate using XML?

Or is it JSON only?

Comment: Are you trying to an API using Spring RestController that returns XML? Spring RestTemplate should be able to do it

Comment: @DhawalKapil Yes. We have an existing .Net Restful server and I'm creating a Java one to match. Some of the existing clients use XML for communication so we must support that.

Comment: If you want to return XML data you have to add a Jackson Library to your project (https://rieckpil.de/spring-web-mvc-cheat-sheet/#how-can-i-return-xml-from-my-spring-mvc-controller). By default you only get JSON if you just use the Spring Boot Starter Web

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal solution that works, the URL https://httpbin.org/xml returns XML and we can use `RestTemplate` to read it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    static RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        testRest();
    }

    @Bean
    public static RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    public static void testRest() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate().getForEntity("https://httpbin.org/xml", String.class);
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
}
```